# Automatically export PDFs with Ms Word 2013 without user input

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word

I am trying to automate pdf generation by calling a locale Office 2013 library, where I then open a document and export it to a pdf.
This works fine overall and I can create pdf files,but as soon as MS Office wants user input the process stalls. Think 'please input a password' or 'too many pages for export' both which generate a popup for the user.

So far the only way to deal with this is to put each call on a seperate thread and invalidate the thread if its running too long.
But I am hoping to find a way where I can avoid all the popups or something similar, as it would be a lot faster then waiting until the timeout kicks in.

Because I assume people would like to know how and what I am calling I'll give a short description.
I am using COM4J to wrap the office library so I can call it from Java, though I haven't found any limitations as a result from it (so far).
From there I call [Document.ExportAsFixedFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840962.aspx) like so:

```
_Document doc = openDocument(inputFile);
try {
    doc.exportAsFixedFormat(
        outputFile.getAbsolutePath(), //File
        WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF,
        false,
        WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint,
        WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument,
        1,
        1,
        WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent,
        true,
        true,
        WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateNoBookmarks,
        true,
        true,
        useISO19005, //Boolean
        _); //unset, null
} finally {
    closeDocument(doc);
}
```

Though I know there are various other thirdparty tools that I could use, but for the sake of argument lets assume that won't be an option for me (my colleagues insist).

I've been digging through the Application and Document methods for a solution but with little luck so far, so I hope one of you lot knows.

Comment: What happens when you drop all of the arguments? ... try this.....      doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(outputFile.getAbsolutePath(), WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, false);

Comment: Then it uses several default settings and still asks for user interaction for certain (the same) situations. So it doesn't help in anyway sadly,

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would try using a third party library to see if it's simply just an MSDN issue (basic troubleshooting).

I looked around and I found this free library thats really straight forward (it even gives you a full set of install instructions to get it up and going).

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/698727/convert-word-file-to-pdf-using-C-Sharp/

If this works as expected, then it's an issue with the `.exportAsFixedFormat` library. If it is still asking for user inputs, that means that you are going to have to go about this a completely different way (maybe even having to create the file from scratch).